# mysql query on negative value

Tags: mysql

I am using following sql query...

```
 SELECT COALESCE(s.open_bal,0)
        AS open_balance
      , COALESCE(sum(i.amount),0)
        AS gross_fee
      , COALESCE(sum(i.discount),0)
        AS discount 
      , COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount),0)
        AS net_payable
      , COALESCE(SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee),0)
        AS net_recieved
      , COALESCE(sum(i.amount), 0)
          - COALESCE(sum(i.discount), 0)
          - COALESCE(SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee), 0)
        AS balance_due
      , b.name
        AS batch
      , b.id 
        AS batch_id
 FROM batches
```

Comment: Can you post full query and be more precise on what to do with negative balance?

Comment: @Victor Sergienko full query added.

Comment: @seoppc: Now, if `open_balance >= 0` it should stay as it is, and if `open_balance < 0` then `net_payable=net_payable - 500` ? Or `net_payable=net_payable + open_balance` in that case?

Comment: right ypercube net_payable=net_payable + open_balance

Comment: Strange one for me - you use GROUP BY clause, but first column `open_balance` without any aggregate function.

Comment: @Devart, yes please help me to rewrite the code

Comment: @seoppc: It would be good if you edited your question and added at the end a few rows from the joined tables and the results you expect.

Comment: @ypercube  check results

Comment: Please provide a few rows from your data, too. Not only results (which seems wrong too. Where is batch_id?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just add [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for a negative balance:

```
COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount), 0) 
+ IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0) 
AS net_payable
```

**edit**: Moving on to fix the query.

*going down from subscribers to both invoices and receipts is wrong idea itself. You're joining receipts to invoices, and if there are more then 1 of any, the other side of join will be summed twice (N times, actually).*

Now, I'll give a basic idea how the query should look. I'm not going into COALESCE() thing - I believe it's unnecessary, as `SUM()` shouldn't return `NULL`s.

```
select
    b.name as batch_name,
    b.id as batch_id,
    s.open_bal as open_balance,
    invoices_sum.amount_sum as gross_fee,
    invoices_sum.discount_sum as discount,
    invoices_sum.amount_sum - invoices_sum.discount_sum
    + if(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0) as net_payable,
    recipts_sum.fee_sum as net_recieved
from fm_batches b
left join subscribers as s
    on batch = b.id
left join (
  select student_id, sum(amount) as amount_sum, sum(discount) as discount_sum
  from invoices
  group by student_id
) as invoices_sum
    on s.id = invoices_sum.student_id
left join (
  select student_id, sum(reg_fee + tut_fee + other_fee) as fee_sum
  from recipts
  group by student_id
) as recipts_sum
    on s.id = recipts_sum.student_id
```

You get the idea.

Comment: looks good, but the value for s.open_bal can be positive also. open_bal is a column in subscriber table, where it can have be 0, + or - value  and we would to add it to net_payable incase if its positive and its negative then subtract

Comment: We won't - see what `IF()` does. If it's not negative, this would add 0.

Comment: and would it add incase of 500 not 0 and - value

Comment: Can you please read IF description (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and look once again at the statement: `IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0)`? I also removed unnecessary `COALESCE()` from my answer.

Comment: its giving wrong results, check this returned row: open_bal: -25000, gross_fee: 90000, discount:0, net_payable: 95000, net_recieved: 102500, balance_due: -12500

Comment: Weird. What will just `IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0) AS balance_payment` return?

Comment: `IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0) AS net_payable` is returning -25000 as net_payable

Comment: -25000, not 25000? And COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount), 0) returns 90000?

Comment: IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0) AS net_payable is returning -25000 and COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount), 0) returns 90000

Comment: Weird. Two things look impossible to me: `IF(s.open_bal < 0, -s.open_bal, 0)` returning negative, and `-25000+90000` returning `95000`. No joint should affect these expressions - I see no way how it can happen. Are you copying the exact text, no changes?

Comment: ok `IF(sum(s.open_bal) < 0, -sum(s.open_bal), 0) AS balance_payment` is returning 25000 as balance_payment

Comment: 1 more thing i noticed, i have tried `SELECT sum( open_bal ) FROM `subscribers`WHERE batch =6` and it reurtn -20000 not -25000 so i think there is some mistake in sql query as well, may be on Left join, can you have a look once.

Comment: Ooh, I hoped the query was working. 

Generally, going up from `batches` to `subscribers` and then down again to `invoices` and `receipts` is wrong idea itself. You're joining `batches` to `invoices`, and if there are more then 1 of any, the other side of `join` will be `sum`med twice (N times, actually). 

So you need 3 subqueries to sum each of: `batches`, `invoices` and `receipts` by `subscriber`, and then to `left join` all three to `subscribers`.

Now I'm a little tired of this question and will leave this to you for now.

Comment: please check the question again for returned results.

Comment: Oh, OK %) I just tell you that it's not going to work - the sums will be wrong. I'll update my answer, having the knowledge that it never worked correctly %)

Comment: RIGHT IT NEVER WORKED CORRECTLY, i knew i am doing something wrong with my query, thanks for great help.

Comment: Edited the answer - I believe you can complete it.

Comment: i just have a  last question about `invoices_sum.amount_sum` , why did you use that?

Comment: @seoppc: What Victor is doing is: first group the two tables separately (invoices and recipts) and sum what is needed to be summed, then join with subscribers. This way, only 1 row (with the summed values) from the (grouped) tables will be related to every subscriber (id). So, you will not have erroneous results.

Answer (score 0):

`(COALESCE(sum(i.amount) - sum(i.discount),0) - COALESCE(s.open_bal,0)) AS net_payable`

Comment: Please refrain from just posting code without explanations. Thanks.

Comment: I would, if the question wasn't edited 3 times while I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can rewrite your query as:

```
 SELECT open_balance
      , gross_fee
      , discount 
      , ( gross_fee - discount )
          AS net_payable
      , net_recieved
      , ( gross_fee - discount - net_recieved )
          AS balance_due
      , batch
      , batch_id
 FROM
 ( SELECT COALESCE(s.open_bal,0)
            AS open_balance
        , COALESCE(sum(i.amount),0)
            AS gross_fee
        , COALESCE(sum(i.discount),0)
            AS discount 
        , COALESCE(SUM(r.reg_fee+r.tut_fee+r.other_fee),0)
            AS net_recieved
        , b.name
            AS batch
        , b.id 
            AS batch_id
   FROM fm_batches b 
       LEFT JOIN subscribers s
           ON s.batch = b.id
       LEFT JOIN invoices i 
           ON i.student_id = s.id 
       LEFT JOIN recipts r 
           ON r.student_id = s.id 
           AND r.status = "confirmed"
   GROUP BY b.name
 ) AS grp
```

Then, change:

```
  , ( gross_fee - discount )
      AS net_payable
```

into:

```
  , ( gross_fee - discount )
      + IF( open_balance >= 0 , 0 , open_balance )
      AS net_payable
```

Comment: mysql throwing error `Unknown column 'gross_fee' in 'field list' `

Comment: @seoppc: corrected. Please provide more details on your data.

Comment: @seoppc: Please provide a few rows from your data, too. Not only results. So we understand the relationship between the tables and check if there is an error in the logic.